# How to tile Height Map in blender

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

I have a texture on a plane. I can there tile the

- normal map
- albedo map
- roughness map

But not the height map. I can't tile the height map, it always stays the same, no matter what I try. I also changed in the displace modifier  texture coordinates to "global". I also tried to tile the bump map on a plane with a smooth shaded surface, but there is no difference.

[image]

So how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117844/discussion-on-question-by-geospike202-how-to-tile-height-map-in-blender).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to scale the bumps with the material settings, as the bumps that we see are real bumps, not procedural bumps. If you want more bumps you need to duplicate x4 your mesh in *Edit* mode and stick each part (there are several ways to do it but you could simply duplicate and merge the vertice by distance so that the vertices stick, or symmetrize it, etc). You could also bake the real bumps and use the result in a *Displace* modifier, or in a *Displacement* node if you want to make it procedural.

A quick way to fake bumps: Plug a *Noise Texture* into a *Bump* node. In that case your object can be low-poly (here, one face) as the bump effect doesn't need any geometry.

[image]

Comment: But what is, if I want to apply my 1600x1600 texture on a more complex mesh, like as a tree bark, which would be then applied on a complex cylinder? The texture (albedo) will then look distorted on the Z-Axis. It would not be a problem to scale the albedo then. But here is the problem: The bumps can't be scaled. And than there are bumps on the tree bark, where I don't want them to be, and on a tree it isn't possible to do the "stick each part" method. 1st because it will be applied itself and then i have the texture on the whole tree and 2nd there would be to many surfaces on the cylinder.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand everything but first you should tell a bit more about your goal, are you working for a game, for a video clip, is it supposed to be exported, or will you stay in Blender, do you want to see real bumps (like for your current file) or do you prefer procedural bumps (the topology will be low-poly and you'll use a Bump node to fake the bumps), etc, etc... as long as you don't give any details it's hard to answer.

Comment: If you want to stay as low poly as possible and if you don't need to have real displacement, use Bump or Normal maps. In your case it means that you can simplify your current mesh and you need to use a bump map (it can be a Noise Texture)

Comment: Ok I will tell about my goal, I hope the English is okay. So I want to make a little "world", which I can use to make video Clips in high quality. What I want there to be is a real world, which looks in all ways as real as possible. So then, if I make the camera move through my little "city" it should look like if I would have made the video with a drone in real world. I want to model my village where I live in blender and make videos, but IN blender, not in my village. I make pictures with my camea from different objects in my village, then i have the textures.

Comment: I make my maps on my own with the program "materialize". I also model the meshes on my own and add the maps to them then, or sometimes I also do photogrammetry.

Comment: And the reason I want to use real bumps is because it could be, that i will also get near to some objects with the camera (for the video clip(s)) and then I want to see the real bumps. But I know that I can use fake bumps and I also know how to but I don't in most cases because with real bumps, there will ever be better quality. I want the highest resolution, I want the best.

Comment: Try to fake 3D as much as possible, for example in your case you probably don't need real displacement for your ground, it will be heavy to handle and to calculate, instead use fake 3D as much as possible, it means use Bump or Normal nodes to fake the 3D bumps, you can use Image Textures or even Noise Texture, as shown in my answer. You only need real displacement if you make some close-up shots where fake 3D become obvious

Comment: Actually you need to think in terms of storyboard, depending on your camera sometimes you will need some real 3D objects, but try to stay as much fake as possible

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will do so! To make fake bumps I can easily use the real hight map, but the only difference is that I don't use the displace modifier.

Comment: if you use height map, simplify your mesh as much as possible, you don't need all these faces

Comment: no, i mean the texture will be without bups even if i have the height map included. Then I only have one single face and there are simulated shadows or fakebumps. however this is called. It will be faster for rendering.